# Updating Django Admin Interface to current look after upgrade

Tags: django, django-admin

Since I updated my application from django 1.7 through every update to 1.11, the django admin interface has stuck to the old classic admin look. How do I update the django admin UI to the current latest look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you run `collectstatic` in production again, to ensure that you've got the latest Admin CSS ready to go?

Comment: Haven't run collectstatic since I have no STATIC_ROOT set. The error I get is 'django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path'